# Labeling the intersection of two rays

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I have the code for rectangle `ABCD` and two of its diagonals. I am trying to draw rays from adjacent vertices `C` and `D`, each of which is perpendicular to a diagonal, label the intersection of the two rays `P`, and draw a line segment through `P` to line segment `CD` that is perpendicular to `CD`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,quotes,backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-0.5,-0.75);
\coordinate (B) at (-0.5,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (1,0.5);
\coordinate (D) at (1,-0.75);

\path[fill=yellow] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

\path (C) -- ($(C)!1.5cm!90:(A)$);
\path (D) -- ($(D)!1.5cm!-90:(B)$);

\draw[draw=red!50, line width=0.1pt, name path=ray1] (A) -- (C);
\draw[draw=red!50, line width=0.1pt, name path=ray2] (B) -- (D);

%\coordinate [name intersections={of=ray1 and vertical,by={P}}] ;

\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]below left:$A$}] at (A) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]above left:$B$}] at (B) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]above right:$C$}] at (C) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]below right:$D$}] at (D) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need an `\end{document}` ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be like this.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,quotes,backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-0.5,-0.75);
\coordinate (B) at (-0.5,0.5);
\coordinate (C) at (1,0.5);
\coordinate (D) at (1,-0.75);

\path[fill=yellow] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

\path[draw,name path=ray1] (C) -- ($(C)!1.5cm!90:(A)$);
\path[draw,name path=ray2] (D) -- ($(D)!1.5cm!-90:(B)$);

\draw[draw=red!50, line width=0.1pt] (A) -- (C);
\draw[draw=red!50, line width=0.1pt] (B) -- (D);

\coordinate [name intersections={of=ray1 and ray2,by={P}}] ;

\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0pt,label={right:$P$}] at (P) {};
\draw (P) -- ($(D)!(P)!(C)$);

\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]below left:$A$}] at (A) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]above left:$B$}] at (B) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]above right:$C$}] at (C) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]below right:$D$}] at (D) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Interesting. Haven't ever used `($(D)!1.5cm!-90:(B)$)` or `($(D)!(P)!(C)$)`. (Just looked them up.)

Comment: Thanks. I know. That's what the TikZ manual said just now when I looked it up ;).

Comment: @Harish Kumar  I prefer your code because you keep most of my code. Doing so is particularly helpful because I can easily determine where I am misusing commands.

Comment: @Harish Kumar  I see that one reason that I couldn't plot `P` correctly is that I had "vertical" instead of "ray2"!  I also see that you replaced `\path (C) -- ($(C)!1.5cm!90:(A)$);` with `\path[draw,name path=ray1] (C) -- ($(C)!1.5cm!90:(A)$);` and that you replaced `\path (D) -- ($(D)!1.5cm!-90:(B)$);` with `\path[draw,name path=ray2] (D) -- ($(D)!1.5cm!-90:(B)$);` to get point `P` as the intersection of `ray1` and `ray2`.  This is more efficient code than what I was using.

Comment: @Harish Kumar  By the way, I removed the `draw` option from the commands to draw `ray1` and `ray2` and added `\draw (C) -- (P) -- (D);` at the end of the code to simply have a triangle sharing its base with the right side of the rectangle.

Comment: @user143462 `\path[draw,...` will enable you to see what and where you are drawing. I left it as a clue. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? Mine is different, I think, from Harish Kumar's so I will post even though he answered first. Note that with my method, the second intersection point is the one you want, so I named the first one Q just so the second would be P.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,quotes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    my circle/.style={outer sep=0pt, circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt},
    my ray/.style={draw=red!50, line width=.1pt}
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (-0.5,-0.75);
    \coordinate (B) at (-0.5,0.5);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,0.5);
    \coordinate (D) at (1,-0.75);

    \path[fill=yellow] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

    \pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{atan(1.5/1.25)}
    \path [my ray, name path=ray1] (A) -- (C) -- +(-\myresult:1);
    \path [my ray, name path=ray2] (B) -- (D) -- +(\myresult:1);

    \path [name intersections={of=ray1 and ray2, by={Q,P}}] (P) node [right] {P} ;
    \draw (P) -- (C |- P);

    \node[my circle,label={[fill=white]below left:$A$}] at (A) {};
    \node[my circle,label={[fill=white]above left:$B$}] at (B) {};
    \node[my circle,label={[fill=white]above right:$C$}] at (C) {};
    \node[my circle,label={[fill=white]below right:$D$}] at (D) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rays and intersections]

Comment: Good that you cleaned up the code. :-). I am lazy!

Comment: @cfr  Your code gives me what I want, but I do not know what some of your commands, like `\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{atan(1.5/1.25)}`, does.  I really wanted to know what was wrong with my code. Harish Kumar found the mistake.

Comment: @user143462 It calculates tan-1 for 1.5/1.25. For a right-angled triangle, tan of the angle equals the ratio of the opposite side to the adjacent. If you have the ratio, tan-1 figures out the angle. So that just calculates the angle you need to draw the ray in. I just did it the way that made sense to me i.e. which occurred to me given my knowledge of TikZ. I guess it made sense to me to draw the rays as single paths.

Answer (score 1):

For whom it interests, here is a [MetaPost](https://www.tug.org/metapost.html) solution, to be processed with LuaLaTeX.

The intersection point P is computed thanks to the following instruction, making use of the handy `intersectionpoint` operator of MetaPost between two paths.

```
P = (C--A) rotatedaround (C,90) intersectionpoint (D--B) rotatedaround (D,-90);
```

The perpendicular to CD through P is simply obtained by joining P to the middle point of segment CD.

```
Q = .5[C,D]; … draw P--Q;
```

I have also added right angle markings, thanks to the `anglebetween` macro which is part of MetaPost's [Metafun](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf) format.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u := 2cm; pair A, B, C, D, P, Q; 
    A = u*(-.5,-.75); B = u*(-.5,.5); C = u*(1,.5); D = u*(1,-.75); Q = .5[C,D];
    path rectangle; rectangle = A--B--C--D--cycle;
    P = (C--A) rotatedaround (C,90) intersectionpoint (D--B) rotatedaround (D,-90);
    beginfig(1);
      fill rectangle withcolor yellow; 
      pickup pencircle scaled .1bp;
      drawoptions(withcolor red);
      draw B--D; draw A--C;
      draw C -- 1.5[C,P]; draw D -- 1.5[D,P];
      drawoptions(withcolor black);
      freelabeloffset := 5bp;
      forsuffixes M = A, B, C, D, P:
        drawdot M withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
        freelabel("$" & str M & "$", M, center rectangle);
      endfor
      draw P--Q;
      anglemethod := 2; anglelength := 4bp;
      draw anglebetween(C--A, C--P, "");
      draw anglebetween(D--B, D--P, "");
      draw anglebetween(Q--C, Q--P, "");
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]